# Distributing processed OpenStreetMap data legally?

Tags: openstreetmap, license

I'm working on different hiking maps, based on OpenStreetMap data.

I want to distribute them, but I'm not sure, if I'm allowed to do so.

Would it be OK to lay them out at a park entrance and accept little donations for the print?

Answer (score 2):

OSM data is released under [ODbL](http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/). In a nutshell you can do anything you like with the data as long as you [attribute](http://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/License) them. I am uncertain on SRTM data. I have always obtained it from USGS who have a [similar](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/citation) citation policy.